# Swift iOS - how to properly use popToViewController

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

it's again me - learning swift.
Question is simple, i have control views like this:
[Initial]->[NotLogged]->[SignUp]
Now after sign up i have double dismiss, it's really ugly!
I wan't to go straight from SignUp to Initial page.
I tried this code but sadly it closing app without any error.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                let controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
                 for vc in controllers! {
                   if vc is InitialViewController {
                     _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc as! InitialViewController, animated: true)
                   }
                }
            } )
```

pushViewController works same as above, there is output:

> 2020-01-29 20:30:38.342180+0100 BillyBill[44355:19540995] Can't end
>   BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 10 (0xa), or
>   it may have already been ended. Break in
>   UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint at `let controllers = ... `, and then stepping through the code to see what happens?

Comment: 1. I’d suggest you `return` after you call `popToViewController` (in case you have multiple instances of that view controller class in your stack). 2. You don’t need that `as! InitialViewController` cast in your call to `popToViewController`. 3. A better way to return back to a view controller is to use an “unwind” segue (which you can search online and find tons of references).

Comment: PopToViewControlles always broke app

Comment: Cant make unwind seque :/ Trying ctrl + drag to button and i can only select view and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can just use  `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController()` command in place of

```
for vc in controllers! {
                   if vc is InitialViewController {
                     _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc as! InitialViewController, animated: true)
                   }
                }
```

Comment: App get closed: Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 9 (0x9), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

Comment: can you please let me know that are you using a navigation constroller or to push to the next screen.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just pop to root view controller

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Nothing happend.